# adding data from userform into table

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform to add data in excel.
The data is been added quite good but the problem is that they are added first in total row then outside the table I have created 
here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Submit_Data()

    Dim iRow As Long

    If adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value = "" Then

        iRow = student.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Else

        iRow = adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value

    End If


    With student.Range("A" & iRow)

        .Offset(0, 0).Value = "=Row()-1"

        .Offset(0, 1).Value = adminpanel.Studentname.Value

        .Offset(0, 2).Value = adminpanel.Class.Value

        .Offset(0, 3).Value = adminpanel.School.Value

        .Offset(0, 4).Value = adminpanel.Mobile.Value

        .Offset(0, 5).Value = adminpanel.Email.Value

        .Offset(0, 6).Value = adminpanel.txtImagePath.Value   

    End With

    Call Reset_Form

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "data are done"

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a Totals/summary row at the bottom of your table then you can't use `End(xlUp)` from the bottom of the sheet to find the next empty row.  Is your data formatted as a Table/ListObject ?

Comment: no i dont have a total/summary row but when i add records, total row appears and the records are in it. i am new using vba in excel so i dont know about listobject, i am adding data in table i have been created in a sheet

Comment: I don't see anything which would add a Total row.

Comment: it adds data first to total row then it goes outside the table

Comment: What is "total row" exactly?  I'm not understanding your description of the problem.

Comment: in excel>in the table Design> tick on Total row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with a Table/ListObject then it has a `ListRows.Add` method which you should use when you need to add a new row.  From that row you can get its `Range` property.

```
Sub Submit_Data()

    Dim iRow As Long, tblRow As Range, lo As ListObject
    
    Set lo = student.ListObjects(1) 'get a reference to your table

    If Len(adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value) = 0 Then
        Set tblRow = lo.ListRows.Add.Range '<< add a new row and get its range
    Else
        'get a reference to the existing row
        iRow = CLng(adminpanel.txtRowNumber.Value)
        Set tblRow = Application.Intersect(student.Rows(iRow), _
                                           lo.DataBodyRange)
    End If
    
    'Fill the row in one operation using an array
    tblRow.Value = Array(tblRow.Row - 1, adminpanel.Studentname.Value, _
                    adminpanel.Class.Value, adminpanel.School.Value, _
                    adminpanel.Mobile.Value, adminpanel.Email.Value, _
                    adminpanel.txtImagePath.Value)
                    
    Reset_Form
    MsgBox "data are done"

End Sub
```